# Accessing variable values in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, global-variables

I'm trying to save the results of a query from Parse to a global variable. However, when I println out of the function to see if the data saved, the array returns blank.

But if I println within the closure that retrieved/saved the data, all the data shows.

How can I save my data to a variable and access the saved data throughout my class and not just inside the function where it was saved?

My code:

```
var itemImages10 = [Int: UIImage]()
var itemImages20 = [Int: UIImage]()
var itemImages30 = [Int: UIImage]()



 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Items")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let imageObjects = objects as! [PFObject]
            for (index, object) in enumerate(imageObjects) {

                let thumbnail1 = object["image1"] as! PFFile
                let thumbnail2 = object["image2"] as! PFFile
                let thumbnail3 = object["image3"] as! PFFile


                thumbnail1.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let image = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
                            self.itemImages10[index] = image
                            println(self.itemImages10) // shows data
                            self.pageImages = self.itemImages10.values.array
                      }
                 }
            }
        }
    }

println(self.itemImages10) // array is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the closure is executed asynchronously, after the data would be downloaded. Make some `Bool` flag that the data is already downloaded and then access it from another parts of code.

Comment: Place the bool before the image is added to the dictionary?

Comment: don't know when you need that data and structure of your application. It could be launching some function when the last item would be retrieved from Parse, or function to refresh something after each item download. Please clarify.

Comment: I need the data for several functions after viewDidLoad. I tried wrapping getDataInBackground with if self.pageImages.count == self.itemImages10.count {] but the data just won't save.

Comment: invoke that functions (where you need data) from the closures, and before that show `UIActivityIndicatorView`s where applicable.

Comment: I don't understand how UIActivityIndicatorView will solve this. Mind showing in code?